How to include an extra directory outside `src` directory in `python -m build`
I have the following project structure
myproject:
    - configs
        - credentials.json
    - src
        - main.py


When i call python -m build, i want a .whl created with this structure
.whl:
    - configs
        - credentials.json
    - src
        - main.py

How to do it? How to structure my pyproject.toml to do this?
